# what to use instead of BigDecimal in low latency trading applications?

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal, algorithmic-trading

using BigDecimal for double value calculation could be very expensive in low latency trading applications.

what is the alternative please ?

Comment: A good knowledge of numerical computing and your requirements. What's an example of a calculation that you would like to use BigDecimal for, but are finding it is too slow?

Comment: You might want to check out this implementation of Decimal for java: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLAPI/weblogic/wtc/jatmi/Decimal.html

Comment: You can't use `double` calculations with money, so comparing anything to it is meaningless. The question is whether `BigDecimal` is fast *enough.*

Comment: @ControlAltDel That is an implementation of *packed* decimal, and it (surprisingly) doesn't provide any arithmetic operations. Not much use here.

Answer (score 3):

Use an `int` or a `long`, of cents, or microcents, or whatever is the lowest appropriate increment of money you're willing to measure.